# Why might the "fatal error C1075" error occur intermittently when using msbuild?

Tags: c++

Possibly related to my other question (note: different error code):

- [Why might the “fatal error C1001” error occur intermittently when using msbuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371600/why-might-the-fatal-error-c1001-error-occur-intermittently-when-using-msbuild)

Our buildbot slave compiles our source code nightly and works most of the time, but intermittently, we see this error:

```
c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xtree(223) : fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at '..\lib\net\CSocketMultiplexer.cpp(62)' was matched
        c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\xtree(427) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::const_iterator' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<ISocket *,CSocketMultiplexer::CJobCursor,std::less<ISocket *>,std::allocator<std::pair<ISocket *const ,CSocketMultiplexer::CJobCursor>>,false>
        ]
        ..\lib\net\CSocketMultiplexer.cpp(75) : see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Tree<_Traits>::iterator' being compiled
        with
        [
            _Traits=std::_Tmap_traits<ISocket *,CSocketMultiplexer::CJobCursor,std::less<ISocket *>,std::allocator<std::pair<ISocket *const ,CSocketMultiplexer::CJobCursor>>,false>
        ]
```

See the [full log output](http://pastebin.com/F1DwjmqW) and [`CSocketMultiplexer.cpp`](http://code.google.com/p/synergy-plus/source/browse/branches/1.4/lib/net/CSocketMultiplexer.cpp) -- Is there anything that I can change in `CSocketMultiplexer.cpp` that might stop this from happening in future?

Also, probably not worth mentioning, but later on in the log, we see this error (which makes total sense, since the file wasn't compiled):

```
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
BSCMAKE: error BK1506 : cannot open file '.\synergy.dir\Debug\CSocketMultiplexer.sbr': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Why is CNetworkAddress.cpp being compiled if the error is in CSocketMultiplexer.cpp? Could it be that there is funny #include of cpp file? Also, does this error happens only sometimes with same source (like a compiler bug), or always with specific version of source?

Comment: @Dialecticus Sorry that was misleading; CNetworkAddress.cpp was the file that was compiled (successfully) before CSocketMultiplexer.cpp - I removed this from the snippet since it most likely has nothing to do with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by this and your other question, I'm starting to put my money on "hardware failure". Could be that one bit in one of your RAM chips is faulty, so if you just happen to hit this very byte, a '}' will turn into something else. I'd run a RAM test tool.

Does this machine exhibit other weird behavior? Rare random crashes, for example?

Comment: Just to reiterate from my other question: Running memtest86+ has revealed 2 errors in the first 2 minutes of running. Perhaps it's time for some new RAM.

Comment: Yep, I figured. That's typically the explanation for random failures like that.

Comment: Haha, I was going to replace the RAM first to be 100% sure you were correct. Don't worry, I won't forget.

Comment: Haha, no problem :) Sorry, didn't mean to push you. Good luck with the RAM. Had that happen to me a bunch of times. One of the most frustrating things to debug since it's the last place you suspect.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

The compilation errors were:

*main.cpp(325): error C2601: 'FLAG' : local function definitions are illegal

main.cpp(323): this line contains a '{' which has not yet been matched

main.cpp(326): fatal error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at 'main.cpp(323)' was matched*

But there was nothing wrong with my code. I counted all brackets and the number matched. There weren't any function inside another function.

I solved it by removing all "//" comments from the source code. It seems that the reason for that is bad line formatting which causes the compiler to miss a line break, so the line after a comment is treated as a comment as well.

For example:

```
// This is a comment

This_is_a_line;
```

is treated as:

```
// This is a comment This_is_a_line;
```

Comment: Glad to be of help