# Why might the "fatal error C1001" error occur intermittently when using msbuild?

Tags: c++

Possibly related to my last question (note: different error code):

- [Why might the "fatal error C1075" error occur intermittently when using msbuild?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371556/why-might-the-fatal-error-c1075-error-occur-intermittently-when-using-msbuild)

On our nightly 64-bit build, we see this error appear intermittently:

```
Generating Code...
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xtree(944) : fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
(compiler file 'f:\dd\vctools\compiler\utc\src\p2\main.c[0x51120030:0x000E00AB]', line 182)
 To work around this problem, try simplifying or changing the program near the locations listed above.
Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++ 
 Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
Internal Compiler Error in c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64\cl.exe.  You will be prompted to send an error report to Microsoft later.
Build log was saved at "file://c:\Buildbot\synergy\1.4-win64\build\bin\synergy.dir\Release\BuildLog.htm"
```

See [full log output](http://pastebin.com/zMMzFfFt).

I get the feeling that this error will be much harder to solve (if this is even possible) than the error from my last question, since it could be a bug in the compiler (but I'm hoping this isn't the case).

Is there anything that can be done to work around this problem? Maybe there's a hotfix that I can't find? Perhaps I should just contact Microsoft through connect?

Comment: Does your system have sufficient RAM?

Comment: Also, you may want to run some tools to check your RAM. Could be a hardware problem.

Comment: Well, the machine is Windows XP with 1GB of RAM running as a XenServer VM, and all it does is build the software -- apart from the intermittent build errors, it's stable. I'm wondering if I should check the RAM of the virtual host...

Comment: Aha! Running memtest86+ has revealed 2 errors in the first 2 minutes of running. Perhaps it's time for some new RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the RAM fixed this (as with my other question with the different error code).

Comment: Well, I get this error C1001. However the development machine I am using is a VM machine! I guess I cannot replace the RAM...

Answer (score 0):

I get this error too (sometimes/rarely on all my systems x86 and x64). Just rebuild and if that doesn't work restart Visual Studio and it probably it's gone. (Nothing too serious ,at least not with my systems)

Comment: Hmm, I'm running it from msbuild.exe (command line) so it's a new process each time it builds.

Comment: Did you try to rebuild or just build the erronous source file ?

Comment: Just noticed\realized  you're using version 9.0. I am using version 10.0 ,so maybe my answer doesn't apply. Sorry!